# Custom error handling in mvc not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am handling errors in my controller and I have `[CustomErrorHandleAttribute]` which I have written what to do when there is an exception in my actions. Even there is no error in my code it is redirecting to customerrorhandle and throwing error. I am not able to find the error why it is doing this.

Here is my code:

```
    namespace ExceptionHandlingInMVC.Controllers
    {
    [CustomHandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public object Index()
        {
            try
            {
                ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
                ViewData["Message"] = "Current time is:" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                var x = 10;
                var y = 10;
                var result = x / y;
                ViewData["Result"] = result;
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw e;
            }

        }

        [CustomHandleError]
        public object About()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "About Page";
            return View();
        }
    }

    public class ErrorPresentation
    {
        public String ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public Exception TheException { get; set; }
        public Boolean ShowMessage { get; set; }
        public Boolean ShowLink { get; set; }


    }

  }
```

CustomHandleErrorAttribute that i've wrote:

```
    namespace ExceptionHandlingInMVC
   {

    /// <summary>
    /// This attribute (AOP) filter is used to override the Error handling and make sure that all erros are recorded in the event logs, so that they can in turn be picked up by 
    /// our SIEM tool  so that we a) stop customers seing a bad error message and b) we are capturing all the events that happen and c) improives security for 
    /// by preventing a hacker from seing s=details of how our application is put together
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public sealed class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This event is called when the action is called i.e. an error has just occured
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                // Bail if we can't do anything; app will crash.
                if (filterContext == null)
                    return;

                // since we're handling this, log to ELMAH(Error logging modules and handler)
                var ex = filterContext.Exception ?? new Exception("No further information exists.");
                WriteToEventLog(ex);

                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                var data = new ErrorPresentation
                {
                    ErrorMessage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.Message),
                    TheException = ex,
                    ShowMessage = filterContext.Exception != null,
                    ShowLink = false
                };

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "~/Views/Home/ErrorPage.aspx"
                };
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method writes the exception to the event log we have specified in the web.config or the app.config
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="exception"></param>
        public void WriteToEventLog(Exception exception)
        {
            // pick up which machine we are on, this will already be set for all websites
            var machineName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MachineName"];

            // PIck up the eventlog we are going to write to
            var eventLogName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EventLogName"];

            EventLog.WriteEntry("abc", exception.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't really need to create your own attribute, simply override `Application_Error` in your global.asax and put your custom logging code in there.

Comment: But to help you, I would bet that the attribute isn't even fired on error, as you've overrided `OnActionExecuted`, which wouldn't happen at the point of the error.

Comment: @mattytommo I am not overriding now and my code works when there is no error and my error handling event is not firing when there is an error

Comment: That's because it won't hit your event on error, you'd have to have a try catch around **everything**. That's why I suggested overriding `Application_Error`

Comment: @mattytommo So you mean I need to add my code in customerrorhandle class to global.asax and how can you please tell me how will I call Application_Error from my controller?

Comment: @mattytommo Is there anyway to avoid entering into custom error class if there is no error and it should only when there is error?

Comment: There is, `Application_Error` in the global.asax **only fires when the error occurs**: See here http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/using-application_error-in-asp-net-mvcs-global-asax-to-handle-errors/

Comment: Should I add it as an answer so you can accept? This will also help future visitors that experience the same issue :)

Comment: @mattytommo yes ofcourse,even I added as well , will delete my post you can add your code and I will mark it as an answer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really be performing your error handling by overriding `Application_Error` in global.asax. That way you can be sure that your code will only execute **when an error occurs**. Using `OnActionExecuted` means that your code will execute **regardless or whether or not an error is thrown**.

Here's the function:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            // Bail if we can't do anything; app will crash.
            if (filterContext == null)
                return;

            // since we're handling this, log to ELMAH(Error logging modules and handler)
            if (filterContext.Exception == null || filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            {
                var ex = filterContext.Exception ?? new Exception("No further information exists.");
                this.WriteToEventLog(ex);
                return;
            };

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            var data = new ErrorPresentation
            {
                ErrorMessage = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ex.Message),
                TheException = ex,
                ShowMessage = filterContext.Exception != null,
                ShowLink = false
            };

            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Home/ErrorPage.aspx"
            };
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

if there is no exeption you need to return, because this attribute fires every time, not only when you have an error.

update:
I suggest to you write code below in global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomErrorHandle());
    }
```

to fire this attibute to all actions. So you don't need to write attribute to any action.

Answer (score 0):

Event should be fired when there is error only and I am writing to eventlog:

In my global.asax I added the following code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Managing errors from a single location 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1. Get the last error raised
        var error = Server.GetLastError();

        //2. Get the error code to respond with
        var code = (error is HttpException) ? (error as HttpException).GetHttpCode() : 500;

        //3.. Log the error ( I am ignoring 404 error)
        if (code != 404)
        {
            // Write error details to eventlog
            WriteToEventLog(error);
        }

        //4. Clear the response stream
        Response.Clear();

        //5. Clear the server error
        Server.ClearError();

        //6. Render the Error handling controller without a redirect
        string path = Request.Path;
        Context.RewritePath(string.Format("~/Home/Error",code),false);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(Context);
        Context.RewritePath(path,false);
    }

     /// <summary>
    /// This method writes the exception to the event log we have specified in the web.config or the app.config
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    public void WriteToEventLog(Exception exception)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("abc", exception.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
```